# How can I trigger a button click using jquery on a dynamic button that ajax is being used on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, button

Ok, I have a form within a Twitter Bootstrap accordion that has radial buttons that switches to different types of the form. They all use the same button which changes dynamically for each form, so it knows the right action to be called.

I have a button on the accordion header that I want to trigger a click on whatever radial form they have picked.

It kind of looks like this:

### Accordion Header                ActionButton

radial option 1 (not selected)

radial option 2 (selected)

input field

input field

OriginalButton (that already works. I want to copy this functionality to the above button on the header)

---

WITH THE OTHER RADIAL BUTTON SELECTED

### Accordion Header                ActionButton

radial option 1 (selected)

input field

input field

input field

input field

OriginalButton (same button as above, but performs a different function based on the different inputs. I need the actionButton to now perform the function of this button)

radial option 2 (not selected)

---

Because the html references different files, I was trying to trigger the button click like so:

```
$side-bar.find('#actionButton').on('click', function(){
        $side-bar.find('#accordionHeader').find('form').find('button').trigger('click');
    });
```

but this does not work, is there anything like this I could use? Just using

```
$side-bar.find('#actionButton).on('click', function(){
        $side-bar.find('#originalButton').click();
    });
```

does not work.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about it way too much. apparently, all I needed was

```
$side-bar.find('#actionButton').on('click', function(){
    $side-bar.find('#originalButtonInReferencedHTMLFile').click();
});
```

I thought because it was being referenced by the side-bar.html file, I needed to .find().find() to go through all the references.

Turns out, if it is called by the side-bar at all, then the side-bar can find it itself without the extra .find()s or whatever!

Answer (score 1):

I've made a fiddle on what I believe it is that you want to do.

Using jquery's trigger method on the radio buttons click events will let you call another elements event triggers.

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
    $('#test_btn').trigger( "click" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Villike/P3V4M/

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. I have updated my question to try and make it clearer. I need the action button to do the function of the button in whatever radial form is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the `#originalButton` object into a variable and then using that instead of `find`ing it again. Perhaps you're removing it from ´side-bar´ at some point and that's causing it to not be found?

Comment: I've already assigned it an ID in html, wouldn't that be enough to reference it by?

Comment: That depends on the scope. `find` will only look in descendants of the element its being called on. If you want to search the entire DOM use `$` directly:  `$("#originalButton")`

Comment: hmm. thank you for your quick answer, but this solution does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you get a undefined object exception or does nothing happen at all?

Comment: looking at your edits, do you have two `#originalButton`? if so, make sure you get the right one. try running `$("#originalButton")` in the dev console and see what objects you get and what their click handlers are. Perhaps you're adding both click events to one button by mistake

Comment: No, I have one button created that is ID = originalButton. But it has multiple functions depending on what radial button is selected. It is done dynamically